Russian declension resources differ
At the moment I a learning Russian by combining a few things. Sometimes I dissect a sentence to learn cases and such. My main reference is "Oxford Russian - Grammar & Verbs".
My issue is the three declension aren't labeled as you find them in other places such a wiki. But then there are some site that refer to it as in the book.
My question is why is that or what is correct? This would help with references.
Example:
Oxford Russian

1st declension
Masculine except those ending with "-а" or "-я" and some neuter
2st declension
Feminine mostly nouns ending with ending with "-а" or "-я"
3rd declension
Feminine soft sign and some neuter.

The first and second declension are swapped on some sites.
I tried comparing sources and it seems the book version is in the minority.
